# How to configure Liferay 6.1 Lucene to store indexes on a SQL database

Tags: lucene, liferay

I have a cluster of Liferay EE 6.1 GA 3 and i would like to know how to configure Lucene to store it´s indexes on a SQL database

Reference from Liferay forum: 
https://www.liferay.com/pt/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/9301810

Comment: There is property a "lucene.store.type=jdbc" which can be used. But since you are on LR 6.1 you won't be able to do that. For more info https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14389830

Comment: Useful comment. I´m trying to confirm if there is no other way besides the  "lucene.store.type=jdbc" property. Thanks for your help.